# Checar URL carregada em uma WebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Boa tarde pessoal.

Em Java temos uma função chamada shouldOverrideUrlLoading que checa toda URL carregada dentro de uma WebView, assim posso criar condições para decidir como o APP deve se comportar. Alguém sabe como fazer isso através do Swift?

Comment: Como assim chega toda url ? você deseja carregar a url e depois fazer alguma ação ? ou quando ela estiver sendo carregada ? não entendi direito

Comment: A WebView vai carregar uma URL. Depois que a View for carregada o usuário irá começar a navegar dentro da webview como se estivesse em um site. Preciso executar um método que verifique toda vez que uma nova url for carregada dentro do webview, para definir o comportamento do app de acordo com as ações do usuário.

Comment: você ja tentou usar o metodo webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: já. mas ainda não é exatamente o que eu preciso..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce precisa fazer o seu View Controller se adequar ao protocolo UIWebViewDelegate

Primeiro adicione UIWebViewDelegate ao view controller que contem a sua uiwebview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```

Conecte a sua webview ao seu view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
```

Adicione o methodo shouldStartLoadWithRequest dentro do view controller da webview:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    print("shouldStartLoadWithRequest")
    if let newURL = request.URL {
       print(newURL.absoluteString)
    }
    return true   // para que a nova url seja carregada retorne `true` ou se voce quiser bloquear retorne `false`
}
```

Nao esquecer de definir que o seu view controller é o delegate da webview, basta adicionar  webView.delegate = self no metodo viewDidLoad:

```
webView.delegate = self
```

[demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iaw7h5bie4ash3t/webViewMonitoring.zip?dl=0)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        guard let googleURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/") else { return }
        webView.loadRequest( NSURLRequest(URL: googleURL) )
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if let newURL = request.URL {
           print(newURL.absoluteString)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```